# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS - Black screen after login

Tags: ubuntu, login

I am running Ubuntu in Oracle VM on a Windows 10 Host.

I restarted the VM because it was rather slow, but after login I get a black screen and I can only see my mouse.

If I login as another user, then it works. So the first user seems to be defect.

Is there a way to repair that user?

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure yet why, but it works again.

Maybe because I logged in as a user, then shutdown and tried it again.

I also pressed on that little gear icon on the bottom right and changed to "Ubuntu Farland" or something